# Excel Graph, if labels exist, delete them

Tags: vba, excel

How do I check if a chart has labels? At the moment the graph is erroring because I am trying to delete labels that do not exist.

```
Sub deltelabels()
Dim x As Integer

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate

For x = 1 To 4
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).DataLabels.Delete
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).HasDataLabels` work

Answer (score 1):

Modified from https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27542370/Check-for-existence-of-data-labels-first-chart-of-the-active-worksheet.html

```
Sub CheckChartLabels()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim HasLabels As Long

    Set cht = Sheets("Page 3").ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart
    For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection
        If ser.HasDataLabels Then ser.DataLabels.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```